# I cannot tag a user in a facebook photo

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I get the following permissions from user

```
create_note, email, export_stream, photo_upload, publish_actions, publish_checkins, publish_stream, read_stream, share_item, status_update, user_friends, user_photos, video_upload
```

(I checked with facebook access token debug tool), and I upload a photo to my Facebook Page and tag the user on that page.

Here is my code

```
$url = FACEBOOK_API_ROOT . "/$album_id/photos?access_token=$page_access_token";

$tags = array(
            array("tag_uid" => $user_id)
        );
$params = array(
    "message" => "",
    "url" => urlencode($photo_url),
    "no_feed_story" => true,
    "tags" => json_encode($tags)
);
```

I curl post this params to the url and get this error:

```
"error":{"message":{"__html":"You cannot tag this user: 10000*******"},"type":"FacebookApiException","code":200,"error_subcode":1610007}}
```

Do I need to take an extra permission?

Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Everything's looking fine here. Is it just for any particular user or is the same for all the users?

Comment: funny thing is, when i google "error_subcode:1610007", only result i get from google is this thread :)

Comment: That is the reason why I asked you. I've been working with Graph API for a few months now and this is the first time I'm seeing this kind of error. Let's wait for sometime and see if any expert here can give his/her opinion.
There's also a [Facebook group for developers](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/). You can also post this problem there if you want.